# Role of NaOH in synthesis of Dithiocarbamate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the role of NaOH in a given reaction. whether It act as a base to removal  proton from amine or just to provide Na ion for the synthesis of sod. dithiocarbamate?

[image]

Proposed mechanism

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{NaOH}$ is used as a base to remove the amine proton, which improves the nucleophilic power of the molecule. This way the addition to the double bond in $\ce{CS2}$ is favoured.

Comment: NaOH can't deprotonate amine.

Comment: @Mithoron to an appreciable extent, maybe, but it's not like it can't happen at all. This seems like the most likely mechanism to me.

Comment: @Mithoron But once the dithiohemicarbamate is formed, sodium hydroxide can remove the proton on the nitrogen and prevent the return reaction. (Sometimes just the order of steps matters.)

Comment: @Mithoron, I agree with your opinion, I think NaOH only act as source of Na ion,

Comment: @Jan, i proposed a mechanism and edited my question